# I need help making a script to color code words in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, google-apps-script-editor

I am working a Sheet to have my students write a story (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3w7SqUFFXLpMve9vX5tbUvNK6Q1pTMu1GfSPs4JQLY/edit?usp=sharing). I then want to have their story in one cell (from my example it is cell L2) I then want to color the words according to different wordlists (columns C,E, and G) so that of a word is in list C it becomes pink in their text.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is not possible to do in Google Sheets by any means. text in one cell (per cell) can be only uniform.